# APEX 5.1 autorefresh Region with variable refresh time

Tags: javascript, oracle-apex

- `P998_SESS_INFO` is my classic report
- `P998_REFRESH`   is hidden item
- `P998_REFRESH_RATE` is LOV with static values of STATIC:

  - 10 Sekunden;10000,
  - 20 Sekunden;20000,
  - 30 Sekunden;30000

I define a dynamic action of type java script expression on change set value for `P998_REFRESH`:

```
$x('P998_REFRESH').value = $x('P998_REFRESH_RATE').value;
```

HTML Header:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  var interval = `$`v("P998_REFRESH");
  // refresh every 10 seconds
  setInterval("jQuery('#P998_SESS_INFO').trigger('apexrefresh');", interval); 
</script>
```

but this will not work. Any suggestions available? Thank you

Comment: Please include in your question why "this will not work"

Comment: no region refresh, because console show error on "$v" is undefined

Answer (score 5):

Two problems:

1 - this code do not start the event change on item. (this change the value on the page, but not trigger the dynamic action).
instead of this

```
$x('P998_REFRESH').value = $x('P998_REFRESH_RATE').value;
```

try this

```
$s('P998_REFRESH', $x('P998_REFRESH_RATE').value);
```

2 - you need to clear the previous setInterval value. it's not enough set new interval. So you need to store in a variable every call to setInterval

```
 var sintervalid = setInterval("jQuery('#P998_SESS_INFO').trigger('apexrefresh');", interval);
```

and to reset

```
clearInterval(sintervalid);
sintervalid = setInterval("jQuery('#P998_SESS_INFO').trigger('apexrefresh');", interval);
```

---

If I were to do something like this, I would try it like this:

1 - I create one global variable in my html header, setting the default value:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  var sIntervalId = setInterval(function(){ 
                      jQuery('#P998_SESS_INFO').trigger('apexrefresh');
                    }, 30000);
</script>
```

2 - I create a dynamic action when change my item that store the interval

dynamic action:
change item P998_REFRESH_RATE

true action:
execute javascript code:

```
clearInterval(sIntervalId);
sIntervalId = setInterval(function(){ 
                          jQuery('#P998_SESS_INFO').trigger('apexrefresh');
                        }, $x('P998_REFRESH_RATE').value);
```

***I did not test this, but it would be more or less that way.