# Update application item after database insert / update

Tags: oracle-apex

When a column is updated on the database (after an insert / update), I also want to update an application item in my APEX application. I've got a *producten* (products) table with 2 columns; *voorraad* (stock) and *min_voorraad* (min_stock).

When the stock is lower than the min_stock, there will be a notification for the employee. But it only updates after a manual page refresh. 
[This](https://i.stack.imgur.com/67i2n.png) is the notification bell, and if the stock has been updated, the amount of notifications should also be updated without refreshing the whole page.

I've tried using it with a trigger, but I don't know how to update the application item. This is the trigger code:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER VOORRAAD_CHANGE_NOTIFICATION_TRIGGER
  AFTER INSERT OR UPDATE ON PRODUCTEN
BEGIN
  SELECT COUNT(*) INTO :NOTIFICATIONS_COUNT FROM PRODUCTEN WHERE VOORRAAD < MIN_VOORRAAD;
END;
```

The name of the application item is *NOTIFICATIONS_COUNT*

Comment: This should be in a page/application process, not a database trigger.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question, you want to access APEX variables from compiled PL/SQL Code. [This Blog](http://George%20Saigau%20%7C%20Account%20Manager%20%20Phone:%20+1-303%20334%206550%20%20Oracle%20University) and [these docs](https://docs.oracle.com/database/apex-18.1/HTMDB/managing-session-state-values.htm#HTMDB29191) may help.

Scott is right - this is better done from within APEX using a Page Process. Apologies, I missed the part about page refresh and only focused on the trigger. TY @Scott for pointing this out.
Page process in APEX docs [here](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/HTMDB/bldr_pg_procs.htm#HTMDB04019).

Also, you really should be wary of using triggers, per Tom Kyte's excellent article, [The Trouble With Triggers](https://blogs.oracle.com/oraclemagazine/the-trouble-with-triggers).

Comment: That may be what they're attempting, but probably not what should be happening.

Answer (score 0):

There are two ways you can do this.

1. [websockets](http://apexblog.nl/oracle-apex-info/sub-apex-tips-tricks/133-using-websockets-in-apex-for-automatic-refresh-with-nodejs.html)
2. auto refresh with a timer

Websockets would be the prettier alternative, but it takes way more coding and infrastructure (Node.js). I would go with a javascript timer which refreshes the item or a region containing the item. This has been explained far better than I could ever do, for example:

https://community.oracle.com/thread/4182574

[APEX 5.1 autorefresh Region with variable refresh time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49450968/apex-5-1-autorefresh-region-with-variable-refresh-time)

Hope this helps!